# "Head First Servlet and JSP" example doesn't work

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Hello everybody i am reading a jsp book "Head First Servlet and JSP" and the next example doesn't work...

**html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1 style="text-align: center;">Beer Selection Page</h1>
<br><br>

<form method = "POST" action="SelectBeer.do">
  Select beer characteristics<p>
  Color:
<select name ="color" size="1">
  <option value="light">light</option>
  <option value="amber">amber</option>
  <option value="brown">brown</option>
  <option value="dark">dark</option>
</select>
<br><br>

<div style="text-align:center">
<input type = "SUBMIT">
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

 <servlet>     
  <servlet-name>Ch3 Beer</servlet-name> 
  <servlet-class>com.example.web.BeerSelect</servlet-class> 
 </servlet>   

 <servlet-mapping>    
    <servlet-name>Ch3 Beer</servlet-name>      
    <url-pattern>/SelectBeer.do</url-pattern>  
 </servlet-mapping> 
 </web-app>
```

**Servlet Code:**

```
package com.example.web;

import javax.servlet.*; 
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*; 


public class BeerSelect extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Beer Selection Advice<br>"); 
    String c = request.getParameter("color");  
    out.println("<br>Got beer color " + c);
}

}
```

When i run it i get... "HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL"... and i'm in dire need for help.
Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: What url are you trying in your browser? What is the file name of html code?

Comment: You need to provide a doGet method for the GET request

Comment: But i dont have any get requests.

Comment: Your example works fine in WebSphere Liberty. For this you DON'T need any doGet() method, you are only using post here. Whoever is saying that is not correct. You may have some problem in your container. What url are you using to display html page and what container are you using?

Comment: I'm using tomcat as the container and my url is http://localhost:8080/Beer/form.html (form is the html file) 
I'm working with elipce and i copied the .class file and move it to the WEB-INF/classes/com/example/web/. NOTHING WORKS!!

Comment: Something in your setup is not correct. If you are creating Dynamic web project in Eclipse, you shouldn't need to copy manually any classes to WEB-INF. It is handled by Eclipse. Maybe your compilation/publishing is failing. Try to create new project, and make sure it is servlet 3.0 not like in your case 2.4.

Comment: I created a new project, Servlet that writes "Hello World" and it worked. So I downloaded tomcat 8.0.14 and i run the .WAR file on it and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by adding a "doGet" method to the servlet.  Use the same method signature as doPost:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     ServletException, IOException
```

What you have coded only includes a doPost method.  Thus the servlet will only respond to HTTP POST requests.  The HTTP 405 response code is the servlet engine's way of telling the client that an HTTP  GET is not supported.

Comment: I don't understand why do i need a doGet method and should i always put it inside a servlet? 
When i add a "doGet" method to the servlet, i don't get the error message but when i push the submit button nothing happen. (I also tried to write doPost inside the doGet method and it didn't work)

Comment: You don't always need a doGet method.  "doGet" will be called when an HTTP GET request is called on the URL for your servlet.  A GET request is what  a browser summits when you load a URL.  "doPost" will be called when an HTTP POST request is called on the URL for your servlet.  Submitting a web page form is one example of when a POST request is issued.

Comment: I would suggest that you familiarize yourself with some basic HTTP concepts.  There is plenty of good info online.  An understanding of HTTP verbs (GET, POST, etc) will help make this clear.

Comment: What i don't understand is whether the browser must create an HTTP GET request in order to get the page from the server, and if so, doesn't it mean that the servlet must have a doGET method.
Any way, when i do add the doGet method, i still don't get any response from the server that supposed to write the color that the client chose

Answer (score 0):

You have all things write,but in servlet code you need to do changes :

Servlet Code:

```
package com.example.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter; 

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class BeerSelect extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public BeerSelect() {
    super();
 }

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Beer Selection Advice<br>"); 
    String c = request.getParameter("color");  
    out.println("<br>Got beer color " + c);
}

}
```